# How does cons work in Haskell :

Tags: haskell

Cons doesn't seem to work as I would expect in the second example. What am I missing?

Here cons adds an element to a list, which is great.

```
1:[2,3]
```

But with this one it seems to put the first element into list x and the tail into list xs:

```
let { myInt :: [Int] -> [Int] ; myInt (x:xs) = xs }
```

I don't really see why this would happen, is it something to do with recursion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's nice to remember that haskell98 allows *infix* type constructors, which must start with "`:`", so the list cons constructor (which takes two arguments) is a slightly special case of this general rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `:` operator can be used to both *construct* a list and *deconstruct* a list, depending on where you use it. If you use it in an expression, it is used for constructing a list, just like you said. When you use it in a pattern, it does the reverse – it deconstructs (takes apart) a list.

Constructing a list:

```
λ> 1:2:[3, 4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Deconstructing a list:

```
λ> let first:second:rest = [1, 2, 3, 4]
λ> first
1
λ> second
2
λ> rest
[3, 4]
```

---

The same applies for many data constructors in Haskell. You can use `Just` to construct a `Maybe` value.

```
λ> let name = Just "John"
λ> :type name
name :: Maybe [Char]
```

However, you could also use it to take apart a `Maybe` value.

```
λ> let Just x = name
λ> x
"John"
```

Comment: Note that there's nothing "special" about `:` here; _all_ value constructors have this property.

Answer (score 9):

There are two different things happening here. Your first example uses the `(:)` operator to create a new list from the element `1` and the list `[2,3]`.

```
1:[2,3]
```

Your second example uses *pattern matching*. The expression...

```
myInt (x:xs) = ...
```

...essentially says "if the argument of `myInt` consists of an element prepended to a (possibly empty) list, then let's call the first element `x` and the list `xs`." This example may make it clearer:

```
λ> let { myInt :: [Int] -> String ; myInt (x:xs) = "The first element is " ++ show x ++ " and the rest of the list is " ++ show xs}
λ> myInt [1,2,3]
"The first element is 1 and the rest of the list is [2,3]"
```

Note that this will only work if the input list contains at least one element.

```
λ> myInt []
"*** Exception: <interactive>:9:34-127: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myInt
```

However, we can handle the case where the input list is empty like this:

```
λ> let { myInt :: [Int] -> String ; myInt (x:xs) = "The first element is " ++ show x ++ " and the rest of the list is " ++ show xs; myInt _ = "empty list"}
λ> myInt []
"empty list"
```

Comment: this answer more completely gets to the problem of the OP.